# Get body response from webclient uploadstring

Tags: c#, webclient

I have the following code which post a couple of variables to a webapi

```
n.UploadString("https://192.168.201.10/api/v1/auth/login", "POST", data);
```

I can use  `n.ResponseHeaders.Get("X-Access-Token");` To simply get the post response headers. But I also need the json in the body of the page.
Is there a function to get this result?

Comment: My advice is: don't use `WebClient`, switch to `HttpClient` instead, it's a whole lot more robust and feature complete.

Comment: Thanks I was just checking out to do the same trick with HttpClient.

Comment: Solved by using httpclient